# Hashes and Symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I would like to clarify my understanding of hashes and symbols in rails.

What would be the hash and symbol in this statement please?

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(product_id:
product), method: :post %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
line_items_path(product_id: product)
```

the `{product_id: product}` is a hash represented in abbreviated format.  In traditional format it would be `{:product_id => product}`

`:product_id` is a symbol, which you can tell by the preceding colon.  When used in a hash, you can use a trailing colon like `product_id: product`

The curly braces that normally identify a hash are optional when passed as the last (or only) argument for a method. The Ruby interpreter can recognize a key/value pair and assume it's a hash.  If you had included them they'd look like...

```
line_items_path( {product_id: product} )
```

or in old format

```
line_items_path( {:product_id => product} )
```

Similarly, `method: :post` is a hash... in this case both the key and the value are symbols, and would traditionally be represented as `{:method => :post}`

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 hashes involved in your code:

```
{ product_id: product } # 1
{ method: :post }       # 2 - can also be rewritten as { :method => :post }
```

In certain occasions, the curly braces can be ommited (which is what you did in your example).

There are also 3 symbols involved:

```
:product_id # 1
:method     # 2
:post       # 3
```

A hash is a data structure while symbol is a data type.